# How to find a sub-list of two consecutive items in a list using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

Suppose that we have a list of strings like

```
"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"
```

Now I'd like to search for a **sub-list** of two **consecutive** items `D E` in this list. How can I do this using Linq?

my approach is:

```
int i = list.FindIndex(x => x == "D");
int j = list.FindIndex(x => x == "E");

int p = i < 0 || j < 0 ? -1 : (j == i + 1 ? i : -1);
```

Is it a correct solution? Is there any shorter solution?

Comment: You could use list,Where((x,i) => (x == "D") && (list[i + 1] == "E")).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @jdweng great! why you don't post it as an answer?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could rewrite your approach as follows:

```
bool hasSublist = list
    .SkipWhile(x => x != "D")
    .Take(2)
    .SequenceEquals(new[] {"D", "E"});
```

If you need the starting index of `{"D", "E"}`, you could add a select that pairs up letters and their indexes.

However, the problem with your approach is that it would miss the subsequence if there's another `"D"` not followed by an `"E"`, for example

```
"D" "A" "D" "B" "D" "C" "D" "D" "D" "E"
```

There is a `"D" "E"` at the end, but your approach stops after finding the first `"D"`.

If you are looking for sublists of length 2, you could use `Zip`, like this:

```
bool hasSublist = list
    .Zip(list.Skip(1), (a, b) => new {a, b})
    .Any(p => p.a == "D" && p.b == "E");
```

However, this does not scale for longer sub-lists.

Using a plain `for` loop would work much better:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < list.Count-1 ; i++) {
    if (list[i] == "D" && list[i+1] == "E") {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `if` inside could be replaced with `SequenceEquals`, accommodating sub-lists of any length:

```
var desiredSublist = new[] {"D", "E", "F"};
for (var i = 0 ; i < list.Count-desiredSublist+1 ; i++) {
    if (list.Skip(i).SequenceEquals(desiredSublist)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think LINQ is appropriate here.

A more efficient solution could be to find `"D"` then just check it isn't at the end and that `"E"` is at the next index:

```
int i = list.FindIndex(x => x == "D");
int p = (i < list.Count - 1) && (list[i + 1] == "E") ? i : -1;
```

This avoids looping twice to find both indices, and also still matches if `"E"` appears next to `"D"` but also before it, e.g. `{"E", "C", "D", "E"}`

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see a shorter solution than yours. But I think the solution you propose only works if first string doesn't appear twice in the list. 
For example, if the list was:

```
"A", "D", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"
```

I think your proposal will not work because first FindIndex will return the index of the first "D", which is not followed by "E".

A posible alternative could be (should be tested to be sure):

```
    int index=-1;
    Parallel.For(0, list.Count - 1, i =>
    {
      if (list[i] == "D" && list[i + 1] == "E")
      {
          Interlocked.Exchange(ref index, i);
      }
    }); 
//after the loop, if index!=-1, sublist was found and starts at index position
```

Not shorter, of course, but can be faster if list is very large, because using Parallel.For. A limitation is that if the sublist appears several times, you can obtain the index of any of them (not necessarily the first one).

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant solution is the simplest

```css
Where((x,i) => (x == "D") && (i != list.Count - 1) && (list[i + 1] == "E")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a good general or efficient answer, but concise - as it is a list of strings / characters, you could do a simple `string.Join()` and check for the substring:

```
int p = string.Join("", list).IndexOf("DE");
```

Comment: Yes, if I suppose that strings are just one letter, it doesn't work if the list is {"DE", "B", "C"}