# Does C# provide a way to search an enumerable collection for a sub-list?

Tags: c#, .net

With strings, you can search a string for a substring quite easily. But does .Net provide anything comparable to do this for more general collections, specifically for *ordered* data?

For instance to search `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` for the first occurrence of `[4,5,6]` would find a match but `[6,5,4]` would not be found? Perhaps as a member of `Array` or `IEnumerable`? It's an easy thing to roll but it seems likely it probably exists somewhere?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find a sub-list of two consecutive items in a list using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35379419/how-to-find-a-sub-list-of-two-consecutive-items-in-a-list-using-linq)

Comment: @asaf92 it's close and if there is no built-in method that might be the best approach but it's basically the same as rolling my own I think?

Comment: @Mr.Boy There is no built-in method. It's _possible_ that someone else has created a method to do so in a 3rd party library, it's not enough of a common use-case to be in the standard Linq library.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that you have the following arrays as you proposed:

```
var target = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
var testA = new int[] { 4, 5, 6 };
var testB = new int[] { 6, 5, 4 };
```

Then you can search for a particular pattern in a given order by combining the `Intersect` and `SequenceEqual` methods:

```
Console.WriteLine(target.Intersect(testA).SequenceEqual(testA)); //true
Console.WriteLine(target.Intersect(testB).SequenceEqual(testB)); //false
```

Comment: This would work for the cases mentioned but has many ways it can fail. Suppose the original list was `{ 1,3,4,4,5,6}`?

Comment: This solution only answers to this question: is a particular pattern appear in the given collection? 
So yes, this code does not deal with where that occurrence is.

Comment: That's not my point. For my example, `Intersect` would give you `{4, 4, 5, 6}` which would not be equal to `{4, 5, 6}` so the method would return false even though the sequence is present.

Comment: No, for the { 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6 } the Intersect will return { 4, 5, 6 }. If the source would be { 1, 5, 4, 5, 6 } then it will return { 5, 4, 6 }, which is bad for us :(